# Trying to change xplot ticks to every 12 hours

Tags: python, matplotlib

Trying to change my xticks to be every 12 hours, instead of every 2 days. Also cant get it to show time in the x-axis. Have tried a few things to change the date format, but keep an error about performing formatting on a list.

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

Time =[datetime(2020, 2, 8, 3),
       datetime(2020, 2, 8, 7, 30),
       datetime(2020, 2, 8, 10, 30),
       datetime(2020, 2, 8, 14),
       datetime(2020, 2, 8, 18, 30),
       datetime(2020, 2, 8, 22, 30),
       datetime(2020, 2, 9, 6, 30),
       datetime(2020, 2, 9, 10, 30),
       datetime(2020, 2, 9, 17, 30),
       datetime(2020, 2, 9, 22),
       datetime(2020, 2, 10, 2),
       datetime(2020, 2, 10, 9),
       datetime(2020, 2, 10, 13),
       datetime(2020, 2, 10, 19, 30),
       ]

leftAmount =[25, 25, 20, 20, 25, 25, 55, 40, 35, 50, 30, 55, 30, 35, 50, 40, 50, 30, 30, 40, 40, 70, 20, 35, 40, 50,
                50, 55, 25, 35, 40, 65, 35, 40, 40, 40, 75, 40, 40, 30, 40, 55, 40, 35, 50, 40, 65, 40,]

rightAmount =[50, 50, 40, 35, 50, 40, 90, 70, 60, 75, 55, 90, 50, 40, 65, 70, 75, 60, 65, 60, 55, 110, 40, 55,
                 50, 75, 80, 75, 40, 60, 60, 100, 55, 65, 60, 60, 105, 70, 60, 55, 60, 75, 60, 45, 80,]

sumAmount =[75, 75, 60, 45, 90, 60, 145, 110, 95, 120, 85, 135, 90, 70, 115, 100, 120, 90, 95, 100, 90, 180, 60,
            85, 70, 120, 130, 120, 70, 95, 95, 165, 80, 105, 100, 100, 180, 100, 100, 80, 100, 120, 100,]

plt.plot(Time, leftAmount, label ="Left")
plt.plot(Time, rightAmount, label ="Right")
plt.plot(Time, sumAmount, label ="Total amount")
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("Amount (mL)")
plt.xticks(size='small',
           rotation=45, horizontalalignment='center')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I've removed a fair amount of the data to make it a bit more readable, the length of each list is likely different now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution with minimal code. The only caveat is that I use the [Plotly](https://plotly.com/python/time-series/) graphing library. It offers interactive plots with hover information, but specific to your problem, it handles date and times very well (Matplotlib can be a headache messing with `xticklabels`). For example, when you zoom in, the datetimes on the x-axis are scaled accordingly.

```py
from plotly import graph_objs as go
from datetime import datetime

Time =[datetime(2020, 2, 8, 3),
       datetime(2020, 2, 8, 7, 30),
       datetime(2020, 2, 8, 10, 30),
       datetime(2020, 2, 8, 14),
       datetime(2020, 2, 8, 18, 30),
       datetime(2020, 2, 8, 22, 30),
       datetime(2020, 2, 9, 6, 30),
       datetime(2020, 2, 9, 10, 30),
       datetime(2020, 2, 9, 17, 30),
       datetime(2020, 2, 9, 22),
       datetime(2020, 2, 10, 2),
       datetime(2020, 2, 10, 9),
       datetime(2020, 2, 10, 13),
       datetime(2020, 2, 10, 19, 30),
       ]

leftAmount =[25, 25, 20, 20, 25, 25, 55, 40, 35, 50, 30, 55, 30, 35]
rightAmount =[50, 50, 40, 35, 50, 40, 90, 70, 60, 75, 55, 90, 50, 40]
sumAmount = [la + ra for la, ra in zip(leftAmount, rightAmount)]

leftAmountTrace = go.Scatter(x=Time, y=leftAmount, name="Left Amount")
rightAmountTrace = go.Scatter(x=Time, y=rightAmount, name="Right Amount")
sumAmountTrace = go.Scatter(x=Time, y=sumAmount, name="Sum Amount")

fig = go.Figure(data=[leftAmountTrace, rightAmountTrace, sumAmountTrace])
fig.update_layout(title="Interactive Plot", xaxis_title="Date & Time", yaxis_title="Amount")

fig.show()
```

It's as easy as creating traces for your data, loading them into a `go.Figure` object, and then updating the layout for a proper title and axis labels. No need to worry about formatting dates.

**Here is the resulting plot:**
[image: Plotly_Plot]

Comment: That's great, definitely works better for what I'm trying to do, thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm having issues getting it to load in my browser though, it wont connect :/

Comment: What is not loading? The plot I added to my answer is solely a screenshot.

Comment: When I run the code myself, it tries to open it in a browser page, and it won't connect

Comment: I ran my code perfectly fine in a Jupyter notebook. You may need to add the following to prevent opening in a browser `from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode`, 
`init_notebook_mode(connected=True)`
`plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)`

Comment: I get 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/owner/Desktop/PlotNew.py", line 5, in <module>
    init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
  File "C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\plotly\offline\offline.py", line 283, in init_notebook_mode
    raise ImportError("`iplot` can only run inside an IPython Notebook.")
ImportError: `iplot` can only run inside an IPython Notebook.`

Comment: @JaydenDunn It looks like you need to run my code in a Jupyter notebook. However, you can always download the Jupyter notebook to a `.py` file later.

Comment: I'll give jupyter a shot

Comment: You can also try removing the `fig.show()` at the end and instead just save the plot to an image file as `fig.write_image("images/fig1.png")`